# On symmetric difference of $k$-partite perfect matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, perfect-matchings, cycles

Given a bipartite graph we know that symmetric difference of any two perfect matchings is union of even cycles.

Conversely when is it true that every union of even cycles comes from symmetric difference of perfect matchings?

Can we say anything at all for multipartite graphs?

The problem came from analyzing derandomizing weight assignments for perfect matching identification via determinants.

Comment: Symmetric difference of two perfect matchings is always a disjoint union of even cycles, not only in bipartite graphs, right?

Comment: Fedor is quite right, but the problem might be more tractable in the bipartite case.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay made problem more general.

Comment: So it is equivalent to: for which unions of even cycles is there a perfect matching using half the edges of each cycle.

Comment: yes there could be a graph with even cycles but no perfect matching at all.

Comment: Some more rewriting and the co.combinatorics tag wouldn't hurt this question.

Comment: @domotorp added combinatorics.